# Override JSON Serializer for DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am trying to create an outlook subscription and it looks like it is failing because MS doesn't know what to do with my dates and quite frankly I have no idea why they are serializing like this:

"expirationDateTime":"04/26/2021 7:22:37 PM \u002B00:00"

Is there a way to override the serialization behavior to produce something more like

"expirationDateTime":"2021-04-26T19:22:37.000000Z"

```
    public async Task<Subscription> CreateSubscription(int tenantUserId)
    {
        var client = await this.GetAuthClient(tenantUserId);
        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            ChangeType = "created",
            NotificationUrl = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("owd:WebhookHost"),
            Resource = "me/messages",
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(2)
        };
        return await client.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription);
    }
```

This code utilizes the GraphServiceClient part of the Microsoft.Graph SDK.  The only part of the JSON that looks suspect is the expirationDateTime as I showed above.

Error:

```
"message": "Could not process subscription creation payload. Are all property names spelled and camelCased properly?Also are the dateTimeOffest properties in a valid internet Date and Time format?",
```

Comment: you should show your code. especially the part where you define your model and how you serialize.

Comment: I am not serializing at all, The MS Graph component is.  I am just sniffing the error, which tells me nothing other than the fact that I can see a date that I don't think it is parsing as it expects a UTC formatted date.

Comment: If you cannot override the behavior, you use, e.g., `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(json);` to decode it to `+00:00`. There's the `Encoder` option in System.Text.Json that can be set to `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`: maybe you can find a way to make it the default (not sure whether it can be set somewhere).